# Error while installing mxnet on mac os

Tags: python, curl, mxnet

I'm trying to install mxnet on my MacBook Pro. The first step on their website was to install Homebrew by typing:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

in the Terminal.

This gave me the error below.

> Conrados-MBP:~ conrados$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
>   curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hey @Montmons, everything was SUCCESSFUL, but with only ONE error. The error says**

```
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
```

**Below is the output from terminal when I typed**

```
ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**Output from terminal:**

```
Conrados-MBP:~ conrados$ ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL 

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/sbin
==> The Xcode Command Line Tools will be installed.

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin
Password:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /usr/local/sbin
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod 755 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown conrados /usr/local/sbin
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /usr/local/sbin
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown conrados /Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> Searching online for the Command Line Tools
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
==> Installing Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode-9.3
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate -i Command\ Line\ Tools\ (macOS\ High\ Sierra\ version\ 10.13)\ for\ Xcode-9.3
Software Update Tool


Downloading Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode
Downloaded Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode
Installing Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode
Done with Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode
Done.
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/rm -f /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
Password:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at 50059990 Merge pull request #4053 from MikeMcQuaid/string-undent-fix
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Cleaning up /Library/Caches/Homebrew...
==> Migrating /Library/Caches/Homebrew to /Users/conrados/Library/Caches/Homebre
==> Deleting /Library/Caches/Homebrew...
==> New Formulae
patchelf
==> Updated Formulae
sqlite ✔            fobis               ncmpcpp             sqlite-analyzer
afsctool            gist                nss                 wildfly-as
apibuilder-cli      git-sizer           php                 xrootd
cimg                jenkins             php@5.6             xtensor
coreos-ct           jenkins-lts         php@7.0             yaws
dbhash              knot                php@7.1
di                  libqalculate        sops
fibjs               maxwell             sqldiff
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
==> Installation successful!

==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate user behaviour analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics.html

==> Next steps:
- Run `brew help` to get started
- Further documentation: 
    https://docs.brew.sh
Conrados-MBP:~ conrados$
```

Comment: [Googling the error](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/brew-update-issue-delete-the-path-and-run-brew-update/235) sometimes helps ;). But basically do what the error tells you: open a Terminal, type `rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/homebrew` then press `enter` to execute the removal, then type `brew update` and press enter again.

Comment: Also, if the answer helped out it would be great if you could mark it as solved :).

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is copied from here: [Apple StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/224873)

---

---

I am summarising my answer from comments.

In your case it seems that something has installed a version of curl without https support into your local folder. Maybe you tried to compile it yourself (the standard `.configure && make && make install` procedure installs programs into `/usr/local` for example.

You can force the command to use system curl by replacing `curl` by `/usr/bin/curl` in it, thus use:

```
ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

When you have Homebrew successfully installed you can re-install the curl in your local folder by using:

```
brew install curl
```

There might be some additional steps as you have to overwrite files that are already there. You might need to use the `--overwrite` option.

Comment: Hey @Montmons, I have an update on what happened when I followed your instructions. It's telling me to fix the error and delete the paths. This is all explained down below in my reply. How do I go about doing that?